# LL1 and unambiguous grammar for dangling else

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ambiguity, dangling-else

I am trying to write a simple compiler using Flex for scanner and a special tool named PGen to define grammars.

Now, I am trying to solve unambiguous grammar for dangling else.
I have searched for this.

This is a grammar with dangling else problem:

```
S → if E then S
  | if E then S else S
  | OTHER
```

This is a grammar that solves this problem (via [slides from Berkeley](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp05/lectures/slide9-2x4.pdf)):

```
S → MIF            /* all then are matched */
  | UIF            /* some then are unmatched */
MIF → if E then MIF else MIF
    | OTHER
UIF → if E then S
    | if E then MIF else UIF
```

But this grammar is still not LL1 and is still ambiguous.

When I tried to solve this ambiguity and make it LL1, I faced the dangling else problem again.

Can anyone please help me find an unambiguous LL1 grammar for nested if?

I have read [in a Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10149493) that this grammar can't become LL1. But I can't realize how I can solve this ambiguity.

Comment: The grammar with MIF and UIF is unambiguous. What makes you think otherwise? However, it is certainly not LL(1) and I seriously doubt that an LL(1) grammar exists for the language. (That's what Aho, Sethi & Ullman say, so it must be true :) ). As they point out, it is easy enough to parse, even though it is ambiguous. But that doesn't help you generate a parser with an LL(1) tool. Why don't you use an LALR(1) tool such as bison?

Comment: @rici thanks for your comment dear. It's a project which should be done by a tool named PGen. It is developed by an Iranian professor and uses syntax graphs to make parser. what is LALR(1)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser  LALR parsing can handle a different and more useful set of languages. If you need to use a specific tool, and that tool is LL(1), and it requires an unambiguous grammar, then I think you are out of luck. Although the language is easy to parse. You just need to always shift the `else` if there is one.