# How to Remove the ambiguity from the following grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, ambiguity

Remove the ambiguity from the following grammar

S −−> if E then S
| if E then S else S
| other

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LL(1) grammar for dangling else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149493/ll1-grammar-for-dangling-else)

Comment: I don't think it does, because the referenced question discusses LL(1) parsing (determinism), not ambiguity. See my answer down.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** remove the dangling-else ambiguity. There is such a grammar in "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" 2th edition, page 211-212. However, the book **has** the grammar, but there is **no** explanation for it (or I have not found it).

In the ABNF meta syntax the grammar is:

```
statement = matched / open
matched   = "if" expr "then" matched "else" matched 
          / other
open      = "if" expr "then" statement
          / "if" expr "then" matched "else" open

expr      = ...
other     = ...
```

### How does it work?

The idea here is to avoid the ambiguity by using non-determinism (that is anyway presented already, because every ambiguous grammar is also non-deterministic; in the end I wrote about the differences, that I find to be (too) **often** misunderstood). That means that after a successful parsing there is **only one** syntax tree possible for **any** input (meaning non-ambiguity as you requested). But you will need a parser that works with a **more** complex machinery than the deterministic LL(1) parsers.

Rule `matched` ensures that **every** directly nested if-statement inside the sub-tree will have `else`. With other words, the `then` will have a matched `else`.

Rule `open` ensures that every sub-if statement does not have `else` in itself, or if it does, then its else-statement is `open` in turn. With other words, rule `open` ensures that there will be **less** `else` keywords used **than** `then` keywords used. And with other words, the number of `else` inside the sub-tree will be **less** **than** the number of `then` (or `if`s if you like). That is in a contrast to the `matched` rule that ensures an **equal** number of both. That means that `matched` and `open`, implemented in a parser, are never going to accept the same input, counting from the **first** usage of rule `statement`.

Additionally, because of `matched "else" open` in rule `open`, the `else` will be "attached" to the nearest `if`. This **resolves** the dangling-else ambiguity **before** the parser recognizes the first used `statement`.

### Example

To illustrate the steps that are going to happen, I have upgraded the grammar to allow more "natural" input. That means more punctuation and white space. First the lexer:

```
keyword = %s"if" / %s"then" / %s"else"
```

It groups the input characters into groups when ever possible, and the non-grouped characters become tokens by themselves. For input of:

```
if(x)then if(x)then y else y
```

You have these bytes:
[image: input bytes]

For these bytes, you will have these tokens:
[image: tokens]

Then you have the parser grammar that allows the parser to accept these tokens (case sensitively) and has white space explicitly placed. You can still watch the original one, the overall process is the same. The parser grammar:

```
statement = matched / open
matched   = {keyword, %s"if"} *ws "(" *ws expr *ws ")" *ws {keyword, %s"then"} 1*ws matched {keyword, %s"else"} 1*ws matched 
          / other *ws
open      = {keyword, %s"if"} *ws "(" *ws expr *ws ")" *ws {keyword, %s"then"} 1*ws statement
          / {keyword, %s"if"} *ws "(" *ws expr *ws ")" *ws {keyword, %s"then"} 1*ws matched {keyword, %s"else"} 1*ws open

expr      = %s"x"
other     = %s"y" 
ws        = %s" "
```

After you start the parsing, a parsing machine that explores in-depth the grammar rules, will perform in this way:

- it will enter in the start rule `statement`
- then into the first concatenation that has a reference to rule `matched`.
- it will accept the first tokens that have the characters `if(x)then`
- then it will again use the `matched` rule
- it will accept all other tokens till the end of the input `if(x)then y else y`.
- then will move out of the `matched` rule and will expect its matched `else`, but there is **no** such, because the input has **ended**. That means the parser must go back to search for another way. At this point in time you will have this (partially constructed) syntax tree:
  [image: intermediate tree]
- it will go back to the very beginning of the parsing and will try the second concatenation in rule `statement`, the one referencing rule `open`.
- it will work its steps and will eventually reach the end of the input successfully with this tree:
  [image: final syntax tree]
- then the parsing machine might continue to explore more, but will not find any other syntax trees.

### Related Theory

It is often that determinism, non-determinism, ambiguity, and non-ambiguity are misunderstood. I would like to give an example of each, because I think that the written up might not be clear for everyone.

From the perspective of a parser, the **determinism** is related to the number of actions possible at a given state. When for **all** possible states in the parser at **most one** action is **possible** than the parser is deterministic. I have seen in many places the phrasing that "a grammar is mostly deterministic, and just in few places non-deterministic". That is misleading, because the determinism of a grammar is based on the whole grammar - more precisely its worst deterministic case. For example, the next grammar is deterministic, and when used by a parser, the parser will also be a deterministic one:

```
rule = "a" / "b"
```

**Non-deterministic** means that there is **at least one** possible state of the parser, where **more** than **one** action is possible, for **at least one** input sequence. For example, the following grammar is non-deterministic:

```
rule = "a" / "a"
```

Clearly, you could rewrite it to just `rule = "a"` but that is not the same grammar. Both of the grammars just generate the **same** language. A **grammar** is **generating** the **valid** strings of a language. This **language** **consists** of its valid strings. A parser is **accepting** the **valid** language strings and it is **rejecting** the **invalid** ones.

**Ambiguity** means that the input can be recognized in **more** than **one** way. That in turn means that **more** than **one** syntax tree is possible for **at least one** valid input. For example, the previous grammar (`rule = "a" / "a"`)  is ambiguous, because both of the concatenations have `a`.

**Non-ambiguous** means that any **valid** input will be recognized in **exactly** one way. That in turn means that **exactly** one syntax tree exists for **each** valid input. Clearly for the **invalid** inputs there are **no** syntax trees.

You might have a grammar that is **non-deterministic** and **non-ambiguous**, like this one:

```
rule = "a" "b" / "a" "c"
```

You have a non-deterministic choice at the beginning of the rule for input character `a`, but in the **next** input character it will become clear which concatenation is the **right one**. It is **not** possible, after the input is fully processed to have **more** than **one** syntax tree: meaning the grammar is non-ambiguous.

Clearly, **every** deterministic grammar is also non-ambiguous, because there is **no** state where a second action is possible that **could** lead to a second tree.

Additionally, **every** ambiguous grammar is non-deterministic, because to be able to have more than one syntax tree, **somewhere** exists a state, that has **more** than **one** action possible, for at **least one** input sequence.

The "trick" of the book's grammar is that the non-determinism is **let** to exists (it is actually "employed"), but it is **not** let to propagate **outside** of the `statement` rule, to effectively **prevent** the grammar to become ambiguous.

Now, all of this is valid when the parser processes its input one character at a time. But I'm not going far from here. There are also different types of ambiguity. Some you **can** count, some you **cannot**. But I'm not going there as well.

Disclaimer: I have used screenshots and the grammar syntax of the tool I develop: Tunnel Grammar Studio.